# TCPDF Browser Popup Title

Tags: php, tcpdf

EDIT

in accordance with @Will suggestions here is a simplified question...

Is there a tag I can use in the TCPDF PDF Creator file (example_003.php) to set the browser title to be anything other than the full URL of the php file?

I have tried this amongst lots of other things but it doesn't seem to play.

```
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
$pdf->SetTitle('Title');
$pdf->SetSubject('Subject');
$pdf->SetKeywords('Keywords');
$pdf->setHeaderData($ht='Browser Title?');
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: New updated question with another tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not a browser will display anything other than the URL for a downloaded file (regardless of whether or not the browser displays the PDF) is entirely vendor specific. My testing doesn't indicate that any data from the PDF is displayed in the title bar of the browser.

Something you *can* do is give the PDF file an alternate filename so that when the user saves the file they don't get a weird .php extension on their PDF. You do this with the Content-Disposition HTTP header. In PHP it could be done like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=document-name.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `html2pdf` with `tcpdf` as the base class, it does contain the `SetTitle` function. You just have to create a function override in `html2pdf.class`.

```
/**
 * Defines the title of the document.
 * @param string $title The title.
 * @access public
 * @since 1.2
 * @see SetAuthor(), SetCreator(), SetKeywords(), SetSubject()
 */
 public function SetTitle($title) {
  //Title of document
  $this->pdf->SetTitle($title);
  return $this;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Html2Pdf with tcpdf, you can add a new function called SetTitle and then call it from your code.

Html2Pdf.php

```
public function SetTitle($title) {
    $this->pdf->SetTitle($title);
    return $this;
}
```

yourcode.php

```
SetTitle('Hello');
```